# Use PGP domain key for email encryption in Apple Mail

Tags: mail.app, gpg

I want to send a PGP encrypted email to someone let's say has the email address

john.doe@example.com

The company provides a so called domain key for all email adresses that end on `@example.com`. I have imported this key, yet it is registered for `everybody@example.com` which does not allow me to select this key for `john.doe@example.com`.

Any help is appreciated!